# Dashed lines in ACF plot in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm going through the book 'Introductory Time Series with R' by Cowpertwait and Metcalfe.  On page 36 Its says the lines are at: $-1/n \pm 2/\sqrt{n}$.  I've read here [R forum](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/autocorrelaltion-function-plots-td3303966.html#a3304490) that the lines are at $\pm 1.96/\sqrt{n}$.

I ran the following code :

```
b = c(3,1,4,1)

acf(b)
```

and I see that the lines look to appear to be at $\pm 1.96/\sqrt{4}$.  So, obviously the book is wrong?  Or, Am I misreading what has been written?  Are the authors talking about something slightly different?

*Note, I'm not interested in the 1.96 vs 2 minor detail discrepancy. I assume this was just the author using the rule of thumb of 2 sd's versus the actual 1.96 sd.

Edit:
I ran this simulation:

```
acf1 = 0
acf2 = 0
acf3 = 0
for(i in 1:5000){
  resids= runif(1000)
  residsacf = c(acf(resids,plot= FALSE))
  acf1[i] = residsacf$acf[2,,1]
  acf2[i] = residsacf$acf[3,,1]
  acf3[i] = residsacf$acf[4,,1]
}
meanacf1 = mean(acf1)
meanacf2 = mean(acf2)
meanacf3 = mean(acf3)
meanacf1
meanacf2
meanacf3
```

I always seem to get values near $1/n$ for all 3.

Further edit :  I'm seeing a trend of $1/n-(k-1)/n^2$

Comment: Really, $-\frac{1}{n}\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$? Centered at $-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: In Enders' _Applied Economic Time Series_ (2nd edition, pp 67-68) explains that the $2 / \sqrt{N}$ comes from Box and Jenkins (1976), _Time Series Forecasting, Analysis, and Control_. Enders used the following estimate of $var(r_s)$: $$var(r_s) = T^{-1} \left(1+2 \sum_{j=1}^{s-1}r_j^2\right).$$ Enders uses $T$ as the length of the series.

Comment: The usual limits are critical values under the null hypothesis of white noise, in which case the variance expression in Enders collapses to $1/T$.

Comment: Shumway and Stoffer in _Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples_ use $\pm 2/\sqrt{N}$ as well. See their ACF code available [here](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Examples.htm).

Answer (score 9):

The sample autocorrelation is negatively biased and the first sample autocorrelation coefficient has mean $-1/n$ where $n$ is the number of observations. But Metcalfe and Cowpertwait are incorrect in saying that all autocorrelation coefficients have that mean, and they are also incorrect in saying that R plots lines at $-1/n \pm 1.96/\sqrt{n}$.

Asymptotically the mean is 0 and that is what R uses in plotting the lines at $\pm 1.96/\sqrt{n}$ .

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob.  Am I correct in understanding that the expectation of the ACF at lag 1 is -1/n?  If so, shouln't the dashed lines then be centered there for the first lag?  Also, since it seems what they wrote wasn't a typo. Do you think they mean something different, or they are simply wrong? I went to their website, and don't see it listed as errata.

Comment: For any reasonable sample size, $1/n$ is negligible compared to $2/\sqrt{n}$ so it doesn't matter much. I've corresponded with Andrew Metcalfe and he acknowledged the error with respect to R. I guess they haven't updated the errata yet.

Comment: Technically, isn't the flaw with R and the authors' assumption R was correct?

Comment: There are two problems. First, the mean of -1/n only applies to the first autocorrelation function, but the authors say it applies to all correlation functions. That is their error, not R's. Second, R uses the asymptotic result (as does every other software package I've seen) rather than the small sample result. So R is not wrong, it just uses an approximation that can be improved.

Comment: is this analogous to calculating sample variance using n in the denominator instead of n-1?